# Providing a before_filter in a rubygem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a gem that contains a method designed to be run as a before_filter in Rails:

```
before_filter :method_in_gem
```

It is up to the developer when they want to call this before_filter in their application (i.e I don't want to enforce it on them in any way)

How can I expose this method in a way that the controller is able to pick it up?  I have my method in `gem_name/lib/controllers.rb`

If it's relevant, my gem is being created with bundler.

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
module ModuleName
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def meth(args)
      before_filter :bf_method

      include ModuleName::InstanceMethods
    end 
  end 

  module InstanceMethods
    def bf_method
      # ...
    end 
  end 
end
```

then just include the Module in your controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include ModuleName
end
```

Comment: is there a method that doesn't require the include?

Comment: sorry, I don't know the answer to that